# Firebase db on web server, how many concurrent connections?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Firebase has limitations of concurrent connections to database. This is what I understand if we are talking about clients.

Now imagine this: static hosting of web app (firebase hosting) + "nodejs server" (in reality firebase cloud functions). The web app (running on server) uses firebase database. It only read data from database and inject them into web page. There are no data transfer from db to client. Client only shows the web page from server.

How many connections are used in this situation? I suppose only one connection as the web app is running non-paralel, only singleton.

Is my assumption right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Cloud Functions, your assumption is not correct.  Cloud Functions will spin up as many server instances as needed to handle the load on the functions deployed to your project.  There will be at least one connection for each instance that it spins up, for each function that you define.  Since you have no control over how this happens, you should expect there could be anywhere between 0 and N connections where N is the number of server instances that Cloud Functions needs to serve your functions.